React native webview scrolling background instead of increasing slideup height
I have used the React native webview package (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/tree/74de1f43d50fd94785cae6cf491ef5a4970c7be8) for my project. Everything is working properly, instead of two things (Slideup and a scale) both are draggable. But unfortunately this drag feature is not working with webview. Any body has any idea? My code is =>
<SafeArea>
      <WebView
        userAgent={USER_AGENT}
        onMessage={({nativeEvent: { data }}) => handleWebViewEvent(data)}
        source={{ uri }}
        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(event) => {
          if (!isUriAllowedInApp(event.url) && event.url === event.mainDocumentURL) {
            Linking.openURL(event.url)
            return false
          }
          return true;
        }}
        //onTouchMove={({ nativeEvent}) => console.log(nativeEvent)}
      />  
</SafeArea>  

Thanks alot guys!
I have tried to solve it with scrollEnabled and nestedScrollEnabled. But no luck!!
